# finding the request on a port

Tags: java

how i can write a java program to find the total number of requests which can be found on a particular port with complete specification (request at present,request running & request pending?

Comment: any request that come to access the website <<

Answer (score 0):

[JAMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/#Introduction) api helps you to find various information on specific port. You don't need to re-write anything.